# Login form to be displayed on the center of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using a login page in my application. Each time when I am opening the login page through my main navigation page the login page is displayed on the left corner. I am using a bootstrap css. Here is the fiddle ["https://jsfiddle.net/vkcc1c20/"]

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div id="login-page-wrapper">
                <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
                    <div class="row" ng-show="login_banner_msg">
                        <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-3">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="frm-banner frm-banner-red">
                                        {{login_banner_msg}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-3">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>

                    <div ng-controller="mainController">
                        <div class="col-md-4 login-div">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <strong class="">Login</strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <form id="form-login_v2" ng-submit="vm.login()" class="form-horizontal">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="yes">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                                                <label for="email">User ID</label>
                                                <div class="form-group ">
                                                    <div class="input-group ">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> </div>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="email"
                                                               name="email"
                                                               type="text"
                                                               data-validation="[EMAIL]" ng-model="userData.userid" tabindex="0">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                                                <label for="password" style="display:block;">Password <strong class="pull-right"><a href="#" ng-click="forgotpassword()" class="" tabindex="0" style="color:#23527c;">Forgot Password ?</a> </strong></label>
                                                <div class="form-group ">

                                                    <div class="input-group col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i></div>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="password"
                                                               name="password"
                                                               type="password"
                                                               data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]" ng-model="userData.password" tabindex="0">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                                                <div class="form-group " style="margin-bottom:5px;padding-left:126px;">


                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custButton" ng-click="login_click()">Login</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I added a new id `cont` to center it so it could be :

```css
#cont{
 position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>


<div id="cont" class="container">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div id="login-page-wrapper">
                    <div ng-controller="mainController">
                        <div class="col-md-4 login-div">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <strong class="">Login</strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <form id="form-login_v2" ng-submit="vm.login()" class="form-horizontal">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="yes">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                                                <label for="email">User ID</label>
                                                <div class="form-group ">
                                                    <div class="input-group ">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> </div>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="email"
                                                               name="email"
                                                               type="text"
                                                               data-validation="[EMAIL]" ng-model="userData.userid" tabindex="0">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                                                <label for="password" style="display:block;">Password <strong class="pull-right"><a href="#" ng-click="forgotpassword()" class="" tabindex="0" style="color:#23527c;">Forgot Password ?</a> </strong></label>
                                                <div class="form-group ">

                                                    <div class="input-group col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i></div>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="password"
                                                               name="password"
                                                               type="password"
                                                               data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]" ng-model="userData.password" tabindex="0">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                                                <div class="form-group " style="margin-bottom:5px;padding-left:126px;">


                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custButton" ng-click="login_click()">Login</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4"
```

will do the trick for you. Add this to your div like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 login-div">
   //remaining structure
</div>
```